# What novels or movies are set in these fantasy lands?

Tags: story-identification, setting

I recognize a few, but some I've definitely never heard of. And if they're on this map with the likes of Middle Earth and Westeros, I'm assuming they're pretty prominent in the fantasy world.

Can anyone tell me what movies and/or novels are set in these fantasy lands?

[image: Map of fantasy lands]

Comment: Should this be tagged story-id? It kind of feels like it should, but it's also not a typical story-id question...

Comment: @JasonBaker Not a typical story-identification question, but still appropriate to tag it that in my opinion.

Comment: I'm a bit disappointed not to see the Kingdom of the Isles on there...

Comment: Surely most (if not all) can be easily found by an internet search.

Comment: This map is wrong in that technically Arthurian legend's Avalon is an island and does not contain Camelot.  Avalon is Arthur's immortal resting place.

Comment: utopia is geographically described at great length. the author of this map apparently did not care.

Comment: @njzk2 what a monster!!

Comment: I'm upset that Ansalon didn't make it in :-/

Answer (score 46, accepted):

1. **Krull** is [a 1983 film](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085811/), probably most famous for this ridiculous thing:

   [image]
2. **Oz** is from the [extended Oz universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Oz_books), of which *The Wizard of Oz* is the most famous. The **Emerald City** is the capital city of Oz, and is important to several books in the series
3. **Narnia** is from [*The Chronicles of Narnia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Narnia). **The Wardrobe** features prominently in the best-known book in that series, [*The Lion, the Witch, and the Wardrobe*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lion,_the_Witch_and_the_Wardrobe), and is the means by which four human children travel between Earth and Narnia
4. **Never Neverland** is from the [*Peter Pan*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_and_Wendy) franchise
5. **Westeros** is from the [*A Song of Ice and Fire*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Song_of_Ice_and_Fire) novel series and *Game of Thrones* television series
6. **Middle Earth** (misspelled) is from [Tolkien's Legendarium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolkien%27s_legendarium). Depicted are the areas where *The Hobbit* and *The Lord of the Rings* take place.

   - **The Shire** is actually a moderately-large region (rather than a city, as implied by that map), and is the home of the protagonists of *The Hobbit* and *The Lord of the Rings*
   - **Mordor** is the home of the Big Bad of *The Lord of the Rings*
7. **Wonderland** is from [*Alice's Adventures in Wonderland*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice%27s_Adventures_in_Wonderland) and its various adaptations
8. **Lilliput** is from the first section of [*Gulliver's Travels*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulliver%27s_Travels), a.k.a. the only part most people remember
9. **Where the Wild Things Are** is from the [children's book of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_the_Wild_Things_Are) (and the film adaptation)
10. **Whoville** is from two Doctor Seuss stories: [*How the Grinch Stole Christmas*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_the_Grinch_Stole_Christmas!) and [*Horton Hears a Who!*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horton_Hears_a_Who!)
11. **Solla Sollew** is from a Dr. Seuss book titled [*I Had Trouble in Getting to Solla Sollew*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Had_Trouble_in_Getting_to_Solla_Sollew)
12. **Utopia** is probably from [the philosophical text of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utopia_(book))
13. **Dinotopia** is the setting of [a book series of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinotopia). It later spawned a few TV adaptations, video games, and suchlike merchandise
14. **[Hattifattener](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hattifattener)'s Island** (I'm assuming that's what that says) is a location from one of the *Moomin* novels, Finnish children's novels
15. **Moomin Valley** is also from the [*Moomin*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moomin) books
16. **Terabithia** is from the [*Bridge to Terabitihia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_to_Terabithia_(novel)) novel, and its film adaptations
17. **Sodor** is the land of [Thomas the Tank Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_%26_Friends)
18. **Living Island** is probably from the children's television series [*H.R. Pufnstuf*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.R._Pufnstuf)
19. **Fantasia** may be a reference to [the Disney film](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0032455/), or to [*The NeverEnding Story*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_NeverEnding_Story_(film)) film franchise<sup>1</sup>
20. **Lidsville** is from [a television show of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lidsville), from the creators of *H.R. Pufnstuf*
21. **Hyrule** is from the [*Legend of Zelda*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda) franchise
22. **Thra** is from the film [*The Dark Crystal*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083791/)
23. **Labyrinth** is probably a reference to [the film of the same name](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091369/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1), starring the late David Bowie
24. **Kadath** is probably a reference to [the castle in the Lovecraft Mythos](http://lovecraft.wikia.com/wiki/Kadath), the home of the Great Ones
25. **The Land of the Lost** is from the [children's television series of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_of_the_Lost_(1974_TV_series)), and its assorted reinventions
26. **Newhon** is from Fritz Leiber's [Fafhrd and the Grey Mouser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fafhrd_and_the_Gray_Mouser) stories
27. **Lankhmar** is a city in Newhon<sup>2</sup>
28. **Dreamlands** are from [the Lovecraft Mythos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dream_Cycle); Kadath is located here
29. **[Avalon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalon)** is an island (not a peninsula) from British mythology, notably the King Arthur legends, and hence from every work of fantasy fiction that borrows from either of those traditions

    - **Camelot** is the mythological castle of the Arthurian legends, and is the seat of Arthur's power; despite the appearance of this map, it is not located on Avalon, but somewhere in England
30. **Florin** is from [*The Princess Bride*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Princess_Bride) and its film adaptation
31. **Earth-Sea** (*sic*) is from the [*Earthsea*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthsea) franchise

---

<sup>1</sup> Thanks to Pablo and Martin Büttner for pointing this out in comments

<sup>2</sup> Thanks to user14111 for pointing out the connection between Newhon and Lankhmar, which I'd missed initially

Comment: Great answer, especially the _ridiculous thing_ 

Comment: @Daft My brain refuses to take it seriously. Just...*who* designs a weapon like that?

Comment: @JasonBaker Someone who saw a shuriken and thought it would be cooler if it were pointier.

Comment: Land of the Lost was a TV series (1974–1976) long before it was made into a movie (2009)

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Yep, that was one of the many edits I just made

Comment: The community answer has 31 items, yours has only 30.  I there one missing?  Maybe add the picture with the numbers to your answer and number them? ;-)

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Yep, missed Wonderland somehow; thanks for the tip!

Comment: I have a soft spot in my heart for Krull. Ok, maybe it's a soft spot in my head, but still. Fond memories.

Comment: Was there anything on that map that wasn't Duckduckgo-able?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that "Fantasia" is from [The Neverending Story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Neverending_Story).

Comment: @Pablo ``The story Bastian reads is set in the magical land of Fantastica`` second paragraph first sentence in plot summary... so it is fantastica not fantasia in the neverending story, but that was the first thing i thought of as well xD

Comment: @Armin the wikipedia article uses both Fantastica and Fantasia. Just serch for the word "Fantasia" in that article.

Comment: @Pablo ok, thanks wikipedia for excellency in their articles... i remembered that it was called Phantasia in German, but why would i read a translation if i could read the original in my native language xD

Comment: @Armin "[...] in a world called Fantastica ("Fantasia" in the movies, which is closer to the German original "Phantásien")." Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Neverending_Story_characters

Comment: @Pablo see above comment. (Which makes your guess quite likely actually.)

Comment: Neverending Story was set in "Fantastica" in the English translation of the book, but the movies (which more people are likely familiar with) all used "Fantasia".

Comment: @Pablo Thanks for the catch; added it in

Comment: @user14111 Utopia is difficult to search for, just because of all the noise. Other than that, though; not at all

Comment: Terabithia is originally from  The Voyage of the Dawn Treader by C.S. Lewis.

Comment: @King-Ink In *Dawn Treader* it's Terebinthia, I think

Comment: I (and wikipedia) think you are right.

Comment: Wasn't Whoville meant to be microscopic?

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez - It is - I assume the label "Whoville" refers only to that dot above the 'W' (magnified for ease of reading of course).

Comment: Anent 26 & 27, not sure what distinction you're trying to make. I believe the whole *Fafhrd & Gray Mouser* series (of which *Swords & Deviltry* is a part) is set in the world of Nehwon, and Lankhmar is a city in Nehwon?

Comment: @user14111 No intentional distinction, just hasty research

Comment: +1 for naming Bowie as the star of Labyrinth, instead of Tom Cruise as the wood elf.  ;)